# heroku cli не работает

Tags: windows-10, heroku

установил heroku cli( 64 bit как и ос)
ввожу:
 `heroku login` и консоль пишет :`"heroku" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.` 32 бит тоже пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел много ответов по этой теме, что мол можно прописать путь `c:/program files/heroku/bin` в `path` и будет счастье.

Но у меня все оказалось сложнее. Я устанавливал на корпоративный комп, соответственно, чтобы прописать путь нужно было обратиться к системному администратору (пароль только у него).

Мы с ним прописали путь через `путь>панель управления>система>доп. параметры системы>...`, но при запуске cmd (а я не только заново запустил cmd, но и перезагрузил компьютер перед этим) heroku так и не определялся - cmd сообщала, что heroku не является внутренней и внешней и т.д.

В итоге помогло только открытие cmd с правами администратора и выполнение следующей команды:

```
$ setx /M path "%path%;c:/program files/heroku/bin"
```

И все отлично заработало. Также, если вы хотите добавить этот путь heroku только на текущую сессию работы в cmd, то нужно выполнить следующую программу:

```
$ set path = %path%;c:/program files/heroku/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

Вообще path почему-то не обновился и пришлось добавить вручную.

Вероятно это баг программы, жду ответа поддержки.

Upd:: его пофиксили в новой версии,  подробностей не знаю

Comment: при установке галочка обычно ставится, плюс иногда нужно терминал перезапустить чтобы path применился

Comment: Стояла галочка , вообщем написал в поддержку жду что там скажут